# Inheriting and Building with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I started to learn maven and now I'm trying to make some realworld projects with beginning simple ones. Maybe it looks simple to most of all in here but I really confused about what should I do if I want to package both parent and children projects at the same time.

(PS: I'm using intellij idea btw)

**here is my configuration**

Project A

- assume that it depends on guava and gson

Project B

- it will depend on Project A

Project C

- it will depend on Project B

when I set packaging attribute of Project A to jar, it gives an error basically saying that "you must set packaging element as pom if it's in a parent pom". But I know that if I set packaging element as pom it wont create the package.

So I decided to create another project as multimodule to manage the packaging issues but dont figure it out how! Shortly how can I generate jar files for each of them at the same time?

**EDIT - HERE IS WHAT I DID**

MODULE POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.deneme.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModuleGroup</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <modules>
        <module>A</module>
        <module>B</module>
    </modules>


</project>
```

PROJECT A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mg.A</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

PROJECT B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mg.A</groupId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <relativePath>../A/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mg.B</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>

</project>
```

Comment: What type of artifacts will you be building with projects A, B and C? How are the three projects structured - B and C as submodules to A or all top-level projects? Perhaps post the relevant parts of your POMs and directory structure.

Comment: What does your project-structure look like? Is A the parent of B or C? If yes, this is probably not what you want. What do you expect as result (i.e. what should be the outcome - an EAR-file?).
If all three "modules" are within the same "project", you could make one parent-pom which has these three modules as children.

Comment: lets say all of them should be outcome a jar file. A is the parent of B and both of them are library projects. C is a normal project and it will use library B (and ofcourse indirect way A). I dont want to describe dependencies again and again. For instance I must define all the depencies in Project A and C should use all of them automatically.

Comment: it looks like you defined some modules in your project A, projects which contains some modules must be package as pom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing inheritance and dependency.

**Inheritance**: A child pom inherits all values, like properties, groupId, version, also dependencies. In general you should not use dependencies in parent poms

**Dependency**: A pom depends on some other jar/pom and uses it's contents and also uses/depends on transitive dependencies

As far as i understand your problem you have the following:

1. Project A - a library depending on external packages like gson and guava
2. Project B - a library depending on Project B, and transitively on gson and guava
3. Project C - an application depending on Project B, and transitively on Project A, gson and guava

I suggest you use this **directory structure**:

```
Workspace
|- ModuleProject
|- ProjectA
|- ProjectB
\- ProjectC
```

and the poms would look like this (header stripped):

**Module pom:**

```
<groupId>com.deneme.projectname</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuleGroup</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.1</version>

<modules>
    <module>../ProjectA</module>
    <module>../ProjectB</module>
    <module>../ProjectC</module>
</modules>
```

**Project A:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.deneme.projectname</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModuleGroup</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <relativePath>../ModuleProject/</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Project B:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.deneme.projectname</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModuleGroup</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <relativePath>../ModuleProject/</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>B</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.deneme.projectname</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Project C:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.deneme.projectname</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModuleGroup</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <relativePath>../ModuleProject/</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>C</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.deneme.projectname</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I did as you said and it worked perfectly thank you very much, but I'm asking to understand clearly when do we need using inheritance then?

Comment: i edited my answer, you do it to strip redundancy: the groupId is often the same value or properties which are used by all projects. Another point is DependencyManagement: You can define a dependency version in your parent pom: let's say junit-4.11. Every Child which uses junit as dependency, automatically uses the version number 4.11 (Unless you specify else)

Comment: I understood perfectly thanks again, but there is another question in my mind, let's assume I want to change some methodname in ProjectB but did not compile it then I build Project C. Normally before building C it has to build B because we declare that dependency in Project C but somehow (I have just checked it) even though there is a dependency relation, project B was not compiled. I need to compile issues from top to downwards. How do I trigger compiling of project B with the compiling Project C automatically?

Comment: the normal process would be of compiling every project from new and based on the ModuleProject so you would do: `cd ModuleProject && mvn clean && mvn verify` Be aware that if your .jar files are in your local repository (On linux: ~/.m2/repository/) it may happen that these are used instead of the local build projects. In that case you'd have to upgrade the project B version to 1.0.3

Answer (score 2):

If your project A declares B and C as modules, it must have the packaging element set to pom. It also means that it shouldn't contains any code and will not generate an artifact by itself. It's merely a way of grouping projects together.

In maven, parent pom are used to define common configuration (properties, etc.) that will be inherited by all children projects.

In your case I would guess that you need a parent project (pom packaging) with 3 childrens : A, B and C :

```
parentProject 
 * module A
 * module B
 * module C
```

When running mvn install on parentProject, all sub-modules will be built and produce the corresponding jar (say A.jar, B.jar and C.jar ).

Note that you do not need to declare the parent in child pom to achieve this result, you only need to declare them as modules in the parent pom, which is called project aggregation. Declaring the parent in the child is called project inheritance. You can look at the following documentation for more details :

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance_vs_Project_Aggregation